# using either of biometric or lock screen credentials for biometric authentication in android studio

Tags: android

i was trying to implement the biometric authentication in android studio using either biometric or lock screen credentials and the problem is, the `cipher.dofinal()` method needs an input , that is given as this in the documentation :

```
val encryptedInfo: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal( /*input*/ plaintext-string.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset())).
```

**I want to know how do i actually use the plaintext-string in the code ? 
The plaintext-string is giving me an error. On hovering it says create abstract property plaintext.**